# How to render an continuously generated image on an 3D object?

Tags: delphi, animation, 3d, firemonkey

For an art project I use Delphi 10.2. for a Firemonkey FMX Windows 10 desktop application.

I would like to use a continuously animated changing image as `TTextureMaterialSource.Texture` to be rendered on a `TPlane` in a `TViewport3D`.

The changing image is continuously generated: I have a `TPanel` containing several overlapping `TImage`. By setting the opacity of each `TImage` between 0 and 1 I can blend several images together. By individually animating the `Opacity` of each `TImage` with `TFloatAnimation` I get a constantly changing image. (This is working fine.)

How can I achieve that the animated content of the `TPanel` is rendered in 3D on the `TPlane`?

Answer (score 1):

During design time it is possible to assign `TBitmapAnimation` instead of regular bitmap as `TextureMaterialSoruce.Texture` using **Add New TBitmapAnimation** instead of **Edit**  which allows you to load bitmap from file

[image: Create New TBitmapAnimation]

This newly added Bitmap Animation then has ability to chose two bitmap sources that you can easily fade between.

[image: BitmapAnimation]

And the same way as you added `TBitmapAnimation` as `TextureMaterialSoruce.Texture` you can add new `TBitmapAnimation` for `StartValue` and `StopValue` of your current Bitmap Animation.

This then allows you to nest multiple Animation within each other and thus in the end add ability to combine as many different images into one target texture.

[image: Nested Bitmap Animations]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I already knew that I can use TBitmapAnimation(s) for TextureMaterialSoruce.Texture. However the calculation of the continuously animated changing image displayed in TPanel is much more complex (with multiple effects, x-y-offsets, drawn graphical elements, etc.). Sorry, I didn't mention this in my question to keep things simple. Do you know how I can "link" the continuously generated image to the TextureMaterialSoruce so that it is rendered in 3D on the TPlane?